# Is a matrix row equivalent to its transpose?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices

If we know that a matrix (A) nxn is invertible wich implies that also its transpose, can we demonstrate that A is row equivalent to its transpose?

Comment: In the general case a matrix need not be row equivalent to its transpose.  However in the body of your Question you suppose that matrix $A$ "is invertible", and "also its transpose".  That restriction means that the reduced row echelon form of both $A$ and $A^T$ is ... the identity matrix!  For future reference: you are expected to explain more of your own thoughts when posting a problem than you did here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes! Using Gauss' algorithm you can show that every invertible matrix is row-equivalent to the identity matrix. That means that both $A$ and $A^T$ are  row-equivalent to the identity matrix thus, according to the transitive property of equivalence, $A$ and $A^T$ are row-equivalent.

Comment: What if not invertible?

Comment: If $A$ isn't invertible then it mustn't be row-equivalent to it's transpose. Look at for example the matrix which has $a_{1,2}=1$ and $0$ everywhere else. It's transpose has a $1$ on $2,1$ and $0$ everywhere else. It is clear that in this specific matrix $(A)$ you can't change any colums except for the second column, so there isn't a way to get that $1$ to the $2,1$